# Mapping errors with values in Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I have a REST application implemented using [Jersey JAX-RS](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/). I have to make a mapping between some errors and values.

Something like this:

> 400 - Bad Request -> The request contained invalid data (e.g. missing, wrong parameter values)
>
> 404 - Not Found -> Invalid URL

How do I specify to the application how to associate an error code with a particular exception/error?

Comment: Have you checked [Mapping Exceptions to Responses](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e435) documentation section?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
try{
```

....
}catch(...){
return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND);
}

were Response is package javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  exception mapping feature
javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;

I have sample here, use full content to refer

[LetzRestOnJersey](https://github.com/itzdilip/LetzRestOnJersey)